# What system would you recommend to me? (Details below)

Tags: game-recommendation

As a person that played the 3.5 edition for a long time, I am want to branch out a bit.
I like this system because it has a lot of options and I generally like the feel of the rules.

Now I am stuck in a bind between either trying out 3e, Pathfinder 1 or 2 or 5e?

What would you recommend and why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question would be better suited for a [traditional forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) or [chat].